# Cannot execute method for android:onClick

Tags: android, invocationtargetexception

I have this activity in my application wherein when a user clicks a button, it will execute `CameraUpdate` which is inside a method. Here's the code:

**LocationsActivity.java**

```
public class TermLocActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    GoogleMap map;


    public static final CameraPosition MoloTerminal =
            new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(10.699160, 122.547208))
            .zoom(16)
            .bearing(300)
            .tilt(50)
            .build();

    public static final CameraPosition TagbakTerminal =
            new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(10.761854, 122.577128))
                    .zoom(16)
                    .bearing(300)
                    .tilt(50)
                    .build();

    public static final CameraPosition CeresTerminal =
            new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(10.758862, 122.567774))
                    .zoom(16)
                    .bearing(300)
                    .tilt(50)
                    .build();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_term_loc);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(10.699160, 122.547208)).title("San Pedro Molo Terminal"));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(10.699160, 122.547208), 16));
    }


    public void onGoToMoloTerm(View v) {

        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(MoloTerminal));

    }
    public void onGoToTagbakTerm(View v) {

        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(TagbakTerminal));

    }
    public void onGoToCeresTerm(View v) {

        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(CeresTerminal));

    }
}
```

Here's the XML file:

**activity_locations.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    tools:context="com.thesis.iwander.TermLocActivity">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Molo Term."
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="onGoToMoloTerm"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ceres Term."
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:onClick="onGoToCeresTerm"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tagbak Term."
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:onClick="onGoToTagbakTerm"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/map"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/map" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

So whenever I test the app and click on one of the buttons, the app crashes and the logcat shows this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.thesis.iwander, PID: 28783
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener
          .onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4472)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18779)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener
         .onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4472) 
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18779) 
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645) 
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
          at com.thesis.iwander.TermLocActivity.onGoToCeresTerm(TermLocActivity.java:77)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener
             .onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4472) 
         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18779) 
         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808) 
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333) 
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829) 
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645) 
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I tried to find questions which are similar to mine but I couldn't find any.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.thesis.iwander.TermLocActivity.onGoToCeresTerm(TermLocActivity.java:77)` You have not shown the code to `onGoToCeresTerm()`.

Comment: sorry, I edited the question. same error shows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your object `GoogleMap map` is not initialized, therefore you are getting a **NullPointer Exception**.

## Quick Fix:

do  `map = mapFragment.getMap();`

Comment: thanks for the response. should I place this in the `onCreate()` method?

Answer (score 1):

You either have the wrong names in onClick in your xml, the wrong names in your Java file (they need to match), or the wrong signatures(it should return void and take a single View as a parameter)

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited the question. it shows the same error though.